# ReactJS PWA restore state on re open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have added the application to home screen on IOS

now when I open it from home screen and do some things then close it completely (also in multitasking) and open it again from home screen ,I see the previous screen with previous react states

how can I get notified when user opened the PWA from home screen to restore some states ?

I can get it by listening on `focus` or `visibilitychange` event but they are fired also in browser tab switching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is discussed here:  https://medium.com/@firt/whats-new-on-ios-12-2-for-progressive-web-apps-75c348f8e945

> If you close the screen of your PWA from the multitask mode (killing it), it doesn’t delete the saved state! So if you open the PWA again from the icon, it will continue as its previous state. That means there is no way to reload the app or start it from scratch from the beginning from a user action.

and you can detect standalone mode as discussed here:  https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#detect-mode

> To determine if the app was launched in standalone mode in Safari, you can use JavaScript to check:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone === true) {
  console.log('display-mode is standalone');
}
```